# Query GetChangeSet() to find a specific object?

Tags: linq-to-sql

Giving the following code:

```
Animal a = new Animal { Name = "Rover", Type = "Dog" };
ctx.Animal.InsertOnSubmit(a);
```

Lets say the preceding code is in a method that gets called multiple times. I do not want to submit the same object twice.  Would it be possible to query the `DataContext` using `GetChangeSet()` to see if this object already exists in the ChangeSet?

`GetChangeSet().Insert` returns an `IList<object>` I am drawing a blank as to how to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out... Using the question's code

```
ctx.GetChangeSet().Inserts.Any(ani => ani as Animal != null 
                                   && ((Animal) ani).Name == a.Name);
```

Comment: This code is not good to be honest. I'd use `OfType<T>()`. You cannot use `Cast<T>()` as it would throw `InvalidCastException` if any element is not of type `T`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `OfType<T>()` extension method instead. Little cleaner.

```
ctx.GetChangeSet().Inserts
.OfType<Animal>().Any(ani => ani.Name == a.Name);
```